# Excel Formula to Return all Matches Between Two Dates

Tags: excel

given the data below, I would like to create an Excel formula that returns all of the red product IDs whose sales occurred between Jan 4 and Jan 18.

| Color | Date | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 1/1/2021 | ABC123 |
| Red | 1/1/2021 | ABC124 |
| Blue | 1/3/2021 | ABC125 |
| Red | 1/4/2021 | ABC126 |
| Blue | 1/5/2021 | ABC127 |
| Red | 1/6/2021 | ABC128 |
| Blue | 1/6/2021 | ABC129 |
| Red | 1/8/2021 | ABC130 |
| Blue | 1/8/2021 | ABC131 |
| Red | 1/10/2021 | ABC132 |
| Blue | 1/10/2021 | ABC133 |
| Red | 1/12/2021 | ABC134 |
| Blue | 1/13/2021 | ABC135 |
| Red | 1/13/2021 | ABC136 |
| Blue | 1/15/2021 | ABC137 |
| Red | 1/16/2021 | ABC138 |
| Blue | 1/16/2021 | ABC139 |
| Red | 1/18/2021 | ABC140 |
| Blue | 1/19/2021 | ABC141 |
| Red | 1/20/2021 | ABC142 |

So, that should return:

| Product |
| --- |
| ABC126 |
| ABC128 |
| ABC130 |
| ABC132 |
| ABC134 |
| ABC136 |
| ABC138 |
| ABC140 |

I prefer not use any VBA for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of us that don't have filter(), I was able to find the answer here:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5953-excel-return-multiple-values-based-on-multiple-criteria.html

So, for my worksheet, the function for returning the column of identifiers looks like this:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$21, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$3,$A$2:$A$21)*($B$2:$B$21<=$B$19)*($B$2:$B$21>=$B$5), ROW($A$2:$A$21)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$21))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1))
```

This should be entered as an array function and then dragged down to see all the matches.

Answer (score 2):

If one has FILTER():

```
=FILTER(C:C,(A:A="Red")*(B:B>=--"1/4/2021")*(B:B<=--"1/18/2021"))
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, it looks like I don't have filter()